# How do I ask AngularJS to recalculate the value of a complex function?

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I have an AngularJS controller with the following function:

```
$scope.getExampleValue = function(exampleId) {
  // calculate a value using underscore's _.where()
  // clause against two JSON arrays on the $scope
  // and the exampleId parameter passed in

  return computedValue;
}
```

The function's parameter (`exampleId`) is rendered from the server, so the resulting HTML looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  ...
  <span>{{ getExampleValue(3) }}</span>
  <span>{{ getExampleValue(4) }}</span>
  <span>{{ getExampleValue(5) }}</span>
  ...
</div>
```

The problem I have is that AngularJS doesn't know to call `getExampleValue()` again when the JSON arrays used in the function have changed: they're 2 simple JSON arrays, new JSON items can be added or removed, or properties of existing JSON items in either array can be modified which affect the result.

I've looked at [`$scope.watch()`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) and [`$scope.watchCollection()`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection) but I'm unsure how I can use them without changing my approach to bind against already computed values rather than against the function I prefer.

Essentially I think I'm asking how to notify AngularJS that a complicated bound value has changed, then I could wrap that notification up in a `$scope.watch()`..

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The short answer would be 'use $scope.$apply in the place where JSON arrays are changed'. But consider improving the question with less abstract code.

Comment: If you have the json arrays attached to your scope, I believe that AngularJS will call the function again when the values of the arrays in scope change. Do you have an example where this does not work? A sample code or plunkr perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`$scope.$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply):

When you change the JSON asyncly, run:

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    // update the properties on $scope
});
```